# Revisitig "Can't rename columns that don't exist"

Tags: r

I tried to rename columns which is actually a very straight forward operation but still getting errors. I tried two methods and none of them working. Can any one explain, what needs to be done to rename columns without getting these strange errors. I tried several SO posts but none of them really worked.

```r
library(pacman)
#> Warning: package 'pacman' was built under R version 4.2.1
p_load(dplyr, readr)
data = read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srk7774/data/master/august_october_2020.csv", 
                col_names = TRUE)
#> Rows: 16 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (1): X.1
#> dbl (2): Total Agree - August 2020, Total Agree - October 2020
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
column_recodes <- c(X.1 = "country", 
                    august = "Total Agree - August 2020",
                    october = "`Total Agree - October 2020", 
                    `Another non-existent column name` = "bar")

data %>% rename_with(~recode(., !!!column_recodes))
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    country        `Total Agree - August 2020` `Total Agree - October 2020`
#>    <chr>                                <dbl>                        <dbl>
#>  1 Total                                   77                           73
#>  2 India                                   87                           87
#>  3 China                                   97                           85
#>  4 South Korea                             84                           83
#>  5 Brazil                                  88                           81
#>  6 Australia                               88                           79
#>  7 United Kingdom                          85                           79
#>  8 Mexico                                  75                           78
#>  9 Canada                                  76                           76
#> 10 Germany                                 67                           69
#> 11 Japan                                   75                           69
#> 12 South Africa                            64                           68
#> 13 Italy                                   67                           65
#> 14 Spain                                   72                           64
#> 15 United States                           67                           64
#> 16 France                                  59                           54

data %>% 
rename(country = X.1, 
         august = Total.Agree...August.2020,
         october = Total.Agree...October.2020) 
#> Error in `chr_as_locations()`:
#> ! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
#> ✖ Column `Total.Agree...August.2020` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add backtick when using names with space:

```
data %>% 
  rename(country = X.1, 
         august = `Total Agree - August 2020`,
         october =`Total Agree - October 2020`)
```